# What is proper beam size for 10'-8" spans between columns?

Tags: beam, span-tables, carport

I am constructing a 22'-0" x 32'-0" carport, using pre-fab trusses to span the 22' width.

The distance between columns is 10'-8" O.C. Will using three 2x12 yellow pine, with 2 layers of 1/2" plywood, 16d nails from both sides at 12" intervals be sufficient?

Comment: Is the "distance between" the columns 10'8" or are they 10'8" on-center? If that's the OC measurement, the distance _between_ will be less by an amount determined by the width of the posts.

Comment: ...and the snow, wind, etc. loads are....???

Comment: Is the plywood necessary? Afaik it doesn't meaningfully contribute to the structural strength in any way and it's typically only used to "bulk out" the "beam" so that it's thickness matches something else.

Comment: 10'-8" OC on 6"x6" posts - to rest in Simpson CC46 post caps.  Correction:  2 2"x12" with 1/2" plywood